# Prevent twilio from calling after hours

Tags: twilio

I have an application that is not allowed to call people after 8 PM (TCPA). I push calls in batch. Twilio makes 1 call per second roughly. I want to prevent twilio from accidentally pushing calls after 8 PM local time to the area code called.

What is the approach to do this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: what would you want done with the call , pushed off to next day ? you should be using a job schedulet

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid Twilio doesn't have anything "out of the box" that can help you there. Twilio will continue to make all the calls that you have pushed to it.

You could keep a record of all the calls that you have pushed, you receive the call SID in the response to creating a call, and then as it comes close to your cutoff time for those calls, send [requests to cancel them](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

Alternatively, rather than sending the calls to Twilio in large batches, why not use smaller batches that you can more easily estimate the time they will take to be sent and then stop sending calls for those areas at the right time. For example, if you sent calls in batches of 60, you can be reasonably sure they will take 60 seconds for all of them to be made. You can then stop sending calls at 7:59pm.